# JQuery Complex Client Side Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I'm building an ASP.NET website to allow import of some tennis scores. I plan to have a line of textboxes for Player 1 and a line for Player 2 which allow for the scores to be input.

My first task is to validate that the scores entered are valid. I could do this in code behind in an AJAX updatepanel so it happens seamlessly but I'm wondering if I could do it with client side validation and jquery. Is this more efficient or less efficient than taking up server time to handle it? The code would need to loop through the two textboxes for each set score and ensure that one of the players had 6 or 7 games and was 2 more games than the other player. If not it's either a tiebreak (in which case a pair of hidden tiebreak textboxes would need to be shown) or the score is not valid and the text boxes need to be restyled to highlight it.

Is this viable? If so I'd welcome any pointers to get me going. I've done little javascript/ jquery to date.

Comment: client side is the way to go, since you can validate and give immediate feedback as they fill out the form.  validation is only part of what you need, you'll also need to build some dynamic HTML to support the showing off additional fields.  jQuery will make this process much "faster"

Comment: Client side ONLY is never the way to go, unless you don't care about the data or you can trust your users. As Caimen said, its both. Do both.

Answer (score 1):

The question you should probably be asking is: "Is it secure to validate with javascript?".  The problem is if say you have javascript built to say not allow a score above a certain point, that javascript can be manipulated on the client side to allow higher scores.  The server side is still going to have to validate the score to make sure it is correct, so you will still require some server side validation.  Javascript validation is really only to make things look pretty, it really isn't valuable when sending data to the server because javascript is easily manipulated with many tools.  Firebug with Firefox for example makes it extremely easy to manipulate DOM variables to anything you want.  Here is a link to JQuery validation plugin.  Just remember if you are submitting the data to the server it must be revalidated to be completely sure nothing was manipulated on the client side to allow variables to be sent that were not within specifications.

However if data is not being stored on the server, only locally then there really isn't much to worry about.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree and will be validating all data before submission to the database and use client side purely to improve the interface and ease of use on the front end.

What I need to work out is how to use the jquery validation to compare the values of the player A and player B scores to determine if they constitute a complete set (ie a player has 6 or 7 by two clear points).

Comment: JQuery validation is not really used for this type of validation.  It's used to see if a field has say all lowercase characters, or has numbers in it or not.  The code you need to write should be fairly simple to do with just pure javascript.  No need for JQuery to really get involved with this.  A few simple if statements should suffice.  Javascript at it's core is not really much different from any other language.  If your having trouble getting started with javascript go over to w3schools.com and run through some of the tutorials.